# Pyodbc connection error encoding name too long

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian, odbc, pyodbc

I use pyodbc to connect into a postgresql server over an ssh connection, the ssh connection goes well, but when I try to connect to the bd its returns a strange error:
     encoding name too long
I don't know how to handle this!

```
Conn string - SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=xxxxx_core_xxx;UID=xxxxty;PWD=##@@$;PORT=12345;DRIVER={DRIVER_Postgresql};
```

odbc.ini

```
[DRIVER_Postgresql]
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbcw.so
```

odbcinst.ini